# Trouble converting POST curl from command line to php

Tags: php, post, curl, parse-platform

I am having trouble converting my curl command into php.

This part works great.

CURL command that adds an entry into my Parse.com database:

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: my_id" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: api_id" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d "{\"SiteID\":\"foundID\",\"dataUsedString\":\"foundUsage\",\"usageDate\":\"foundDate\", \"monthString\":\"foundMonth\", \"dayString\":\"foundDay\",\"yearString\":\"foundYear\"}" \
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/MyClass
```

**SOLVED ANSWER:**

I have created this php script to replicate the command:

```
   <?php 
   $ch = curl_init('https://api.parse.com/1/classes/MyClass');

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
    array('X-Parse-Application-Id:my_id',
'X-Parse-REST-API-Key:api_id',
'Content-Type: application/json'));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"SiteID\":\"foundID\",\"dataUsedString\":\"foundUsage\",\"usageDate\":\"foundDate\", \"monthString\":\"foundMonth\", \"dayString\":\"foundDay\",\"yearString\":\"foundYear\"}");

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: What response do you get from the remote server?

Comment: SOLVED!!!! Thank you @valentin and cOle2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've missed some crucial configurations.
These are the set the CURL to send request using POST, and the second is data to send. (RAW DATA is being sent as string into POSTFIELDS, those if you send array - it will automatically append header "multipart/form-data"

```
$ch = curl_init('https://api.parse.com/1/classes/MyClass');

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
  array(
    'X-Parse-Application-Id:my_id',
    'X-Parse-REST-API-Key:api_id',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
  )
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"SiteID\":\"foundID\",\"dataUsedString\":\"foundUsage\",\"usageDate\":\"foundDate\", \"monthString\":\"foundMonth\", \"dayString\":\"foundDay\",\"yearString\":\"foundYear\"}");
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

HTH:)

Comment: I put my updated my code to what you suggested. I edited my code above so that you can see it. A row is still not being added into my database. Any more suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing a `POST` request you need to tell Curl to do that as well:

```
$postData = '{"SiteID":"foundID","dataUsedString":"foundUsage","usageDate":"foundDate", "monthString":"foundMonth", "dayString":"foundDay","yearString":"foundYear"}';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
```

You may also need to supply a `Content-Length` header:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'X-Parse-Application-Id: my_id',
  'X-Parse-REST-API-Key: api_id',
  'Content-Type: application/json',                                                           
  'Content-Length: '.strlen($postData))                                                                       
);
```

Comment: I edited my code and my answer to add my updated code. But still, a new row is not being created. :(